# Unable to get child View html contents with 'RenderBody' .NET CORE?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am struggling to get the child view of my page. Previously, it worked but I don't know what I have done which caused child view to stop working. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
    public IActionResult Index(){

       ViewBag.Message = TempData["Message"];

        ViewBag.Hello = "say hello";
        return View("Index");

    }
```

View:

```
@using MAJU.Models
@using FYPProject.Controllers
@model FYPProject.Pages.DashboardModel

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers  


@{
   Layout = "_Layout";
   ViewData["Title"] = "NManagement - Dashboard";        
   bool a = true;

}


    <body >
        <p>This is Dashboard Body</p>


    </body>
```

Accessing the page from:

```
http://localhost:5000/Dashboard
```

I have tried everything, but `@RenderBody` doesn't renders my page. I think I am doing some silly mistake. Please help me figure it out

Answer (score 0):

First of all it should be

```
@RenderBody()
```

not

```
RenderBody
```

And your controller you just need to

```
return View();
```

Because the framework will search for the view in the folder that match your controller name and your action name

Every project have _ViewStart.cshtml so that we dont have to include Layout page everytime we create new view

The content of _ViewStart.cshtml file

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

Please let me know if you have any problem

Comment: I got it, as StackOverflow wasn't allowing me to put @ in the question :)

Comment: Your guide was helpful, however not fully, as I have to recreate another file to get this work. I will wait if other people answers.

Comment: What error do you have when you run your project. Try to set a break point in your controller and add try catch